# I need to used two different versions of jquery in the same html

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.tools.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

I only can execute one of two. I don´t understand any of jquery  only copy and used.  But in this case  I need to used both on these.

How can I do? please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn jQuery, its good to know what you use...

Comment: Hey guys, Seems like He/she joined today, `:))` I would give him leverage as a newbie! Hey @user1474344 please read FAQ's and be very sure that you know what you are asking, proof read your question and do background search man, D'uh SO is awesome community but any bad question are not entertained, Have a nice one mate! cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Just use the most recent library. It will be backwards compatible.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.tools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

Better still, download the very latest version here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: Many thanks Curt.  As I write, I don´t know anything about jquery.  I´m trying to download from the link you said.  But when I make click it appears the code itself.  Should I copy and paste in a new file?

Comment: I tried to leave only version 1.4 but eighter.  Only works one of the two functions.

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like that ....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jQ3=jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jQ4=jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script>
jQ3(function($){
    alert($.fn.jquery + ' - jQuery - 1.3.2')    
});
jQ4(function($){
    alert($.fn.jquery + ' - jQuery - 1.4')  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Rahen, it gives me a box message  "1.4-jQuery-1.4" (Accept). When I accept it doesn´t execute none of two functions.